# Click element on the dropdown in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this dropdown:

```
<div id="change_booking_status" data-booking-id="99">
    <div class="btn-group btn-block">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Open <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-status="Open">Open</a></li>
            <li><a data-status="Close">Close</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a data-status="Cancel">Cancel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

On each change I apply this code:

```
$('#change_booking_status').on('click', 'div > div > ul > li a', function() {
    alert('aa');
    var text = $(this).text();
    var status = $(this).data('status');
    var bid = $('#change_booking_status').data('booking-id');

    $('#change_booking_status > div > a.dropdown-toggle').html(text + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data : 'BOO_Id='+bid+'&BOO_Status='+status,
        url  : 'assets/php/ajax/booking_status_edit.php',
        success: function(responseText){
            //alert('Success');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is this code do not make anything.

Any help on this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The second `div` in the selector doesn't exist in the html

try changing to

```
$('#change_booking_status').on('click', 'div > ul > li a', function() {
```

or easier to read/understand later on

```
$('#change_booking_status').on('click', 'ul.dropdown-menu > li a', function() {
```